# Android Text in different language take different height

Tags: android, android-layout, fonts, textview

We are showing some text in our application (say in a `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager`). This text is shown in different languages as highlighted in the image below. Due to this, the height of `TextView` is different as different language fonts are taking different spacing.
Please refer to the sample image below and the required code to draw the text view.

```
  <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_title_one"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/lato_bold"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:minLines="1"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:textColor="#541388"
            android:letterSpacing="0"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="0dp"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="Class 12th (Biology) 2021 - 2022" />
```

[image: Sample Image]

---

Dummy layout with two similar text views but with different language
[image: Sample2]

Please let me know if there is anything missing in the problem description. Thanks for your valuable feedback.

---

Update #1:
Since there is no direct answer to it. We are going with making card height and text height-restricted as mentioned in the accepted answer.

Comment: I guess it is due to the  android:fontFamily="@font/lato_bold" font-family maybe it is not supporting in Hindi.

Comment: I have checked with removing font as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just think that the reason could come from the font you are trying to use for rending text in this TV. For every language, the character size maybe vary a bit from width to height due to the language specs.

Could you try to use the default system font to check if you still have that spacing issue?

Or another suggestion would be:

- Use `autoSizeMaxTextSize`, `autoSizeMinTextSize` feature to allow text size being automatically resize to fix the `textview` when possible.
- Apply a fix Height for your text content with extra Vertical Space, and add `android:ellipsize` as your wish.

Still wonder:

- Is your app displaying multiple language at a same time on UI?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried the default system font but have the same result.

Comment: Auto Text size and fixing height might work but I am planning to wrap the height based on content. Making the UI more flexible.

Comment: Yes. English and Hindi are common languages for our audience and for some use cases we are using both together.